# Adding a positive and a negative double values

Tags: c#, .net, double

I've noticed a weird behaviour while adding two double values, one negative and one positive.

```
var eighteenPointFive = -18.5;
var nineteenPointFour = 19.4;

var eighteenPointFour = -18.4;
var nineteenPointFive = 19.5;

Console.WriteLine(eighteenPointFive + nineteenPointFour); // prints 0.899999999999999 (why not 0.9?)

Console.WriteLine(eighteenPointFour + nineteenPointFive); // prints 1.1
```

Why is there a difference in the number of digits after the decimal point in both cases?.

Comment: because double is type of floating-point.  see [Why Are Floating Point Numbers Inaccurate?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21895756/why-are-floating-point-numbers-inaccurate)

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html

Comment: Simpler and classical example: https://dotnetfiddle.net/79FLWb: 0.1 + 0.2 != 0.3

Comment: Use decimals instead of doubles. Decimal literals have the `m` suffix, eg `-18.5m`, `19.4m`. Decimals aren't prone to scaling errors. Several databases (eg SQL Server) even prevent the number of decimals so that `10.50` remains `10.50` instead of becoming `10.5'

Comment: in order to print it accurate.you must round it using .ToString() method. `(eighteenPointFive + nineteenPointFour).ToString("R")`

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary ToString() doesn't round anything. Scaling errors have *already* occurred when adding. Besides, a string is useless for calculations